# Python display labels for the line series chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to build a line chart with the labels, but I can't find how to achieve this. Basically, I want to have value for the point above the marker.

```
d = {'Year': ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'], 'Total': [1133.34262,1139.36454,1151.42072,1134.42854,1127.49346,1121.54558,1118.75674,1112.13016,1111.08126,1112.37696], 'Metric1':[444.4251,453.495,452.59418,454.63028,456.53064,456.17278,456.5183,455.35834,456.49362,456.4566], 'Metric2':[116.78576,116.13174,112.70122,112.49144,111.62764,108.74008,106.40782,105.61806,106.0623,104.74192], 'Metric3':[346.95144,346.24806,358.21786,350.06112,343.00264,338.49854,333.78466,329.88522,329.37928,331.36602], 'Metric4':[224.82246,223.58846,228.0432,217.09762,216.1351,217.83802,221.71278,221.10812,219.05968,219.38052]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.plot( x="Year", 
         y=['Metric1','Metric2','Metric3','Metric4'],
         kind="line",
         figsize=(12,10),
         marker='o',
         linewidth=2
        )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use matplotlib's `text` function to achieve this.

First convert `df['Year']` from string to float:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(float)
```

Then iterate over the rows of your pandas dataframe and plot the label corresponding to `Metric1` above each point of coordinates (`Year`, `Metric1`). You may use a `padding` parameter to improve the visual aspect and ensure that the label does not overlap with the points:

```
padding = 2
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.text(np.float(row['Year']), row['Metric1']+padding, row['Metric1'])
```

This snippet yields the following image:

[image]

You may repeat the same steps for the other Metrics.

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the dictionary values so instead of `x='year'` do
`x = d['year']` do that for all of the dictionary values you need to find